# syncdb doesnt create tables for my app

Tags: django, django-models

Hello 
   I am trying out the django framework, and my project structure is like this

../mysite/src/mysite/models/models.py (models.py containts all defined models)
../mysite/src/mysite/ (contains the settings.py manage.py and etc)

when i run the syncdb. only django admin's tables are created. but my models in models.py are not detected.

In INSTALLED_APPS section in settings.py. i added 'mysite'.

if i change from 'mysite' ->'mysite.src' it will give an error "Error: no model named src"
if i change from 'mysite' -> 'mysite.models.models' it will give 'AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '**path**'
'

can anyone help me with the syncdb?

thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

Move your models.py file out from models dir and back into the mysite dir. Try again afterwards, it should now work... syncdb is reliant on the file/dir structure.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to have a "models" folder containing many model definition files. You should include a file named **init**.py in the models folder where you should import all the models of the application

```
# app/models/__init__.py
# assuming you have main_models and other_models files 
from app.models.main_models import *
from app.models.other_models import *
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ideal app structure is

```
ProjectDirectory/
 |- settings.py
 |- urls.py
 \- AppDirectory
     |- __init__.py
     |- views.py
     \- models.py
```

If you want it to work in it's current configuration (I'm assuming /src is your "project directory" in this sense and has either been added to your python path or contains manage.py) then inside the models directoy include a file called `__init__.py` and add the line `from models import *`. This will import everything and make everything in your models.py accessible by django in the place it expects it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of where your actual project directory is, you need to add the `models` app to your `INSTALLED_APPS`, in python dot syntax however your `models` app is resolvable.

If the top level `mysite` is in your python path, then it would be `src.mysite.models`. If `src` is in your python path, then `mysite.models`.

You are supposed to add the parent folder of your django project directory (where `settings.py` lives) to your python path, so your apps would be referred to as `project.app`

Answer (score 1):

i found where the issue is. my Models.py should be models.py.... should not start with captical M.

thanks guys for your help

Answer (score 0):

add to your setting file

```
import os
import sys

ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(ROOT_PATH + '/src')
```

and then check it again